# Is there a way to get a SIMPLE report using perl NYTProf?

Tags: perl, profile, profiler, devel-nytprof

I installed NYTProf and ran my code using it. Trying to get a simple listing of lines and time spent on them. Good Lord, all this profiler has is html file reports or data dumps designed for import into data analysis tools. I'm working on a remote system and firing up a browser to load file:/// URLs requires setting up tunnels and remote (slow) x-servers etc. it's is a pain in the butt. All's I want is a simple:

```
Function:Line percentage-time-spent  (sorted with longest time spent lines at the top)

    openlogs:27     40%
    readlogs:124    30%
    closelogs:1243  20%
    profile:67      10%
```

You know, a profiler.

This is perl. It's not UX demonstration time. I'm not preparing a report for a Congressional sub-committee.

The documentation doesn't seem to show a way to get a simple report designed for developers to show which slowness to attack in their code. Am I missing something here? Anyone know a way to do this quickly?

Comment: You're looking for a secret undocumented feature? Surely you can just scp the HTML report onto your local machine and look at it there.

Comment: Looked at [Synopsis](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf#SYNOPSIS)? Like at `nytprofcsv` which generates, you know, CSV files with all data?

Comment: nytprofcsv is deprecated https://metacpan.org/dist/Devel-NYTProf/view/bin/nytprofcsv

Comment: @AKHolland Wow -- it is indeed right in the Synopsis (which I linked). But for right now it works (i had tried).  Not a good policy to use long-term of course...  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The way to get a simple profiler output is to use [`Devel::Profile`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Profile)

```
$ perl -d:Profile my_script.pl
$ cat prof.out
```